# Observation is failing at doing side effect

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I'm using this observable to prevent received duplicates or stale acks.

```
import { useObservable } from 'rxjs-hooks';
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
    const ack = useObservable<InstantAckValueDecodedData | null>(() => {
    // Used to prevent ack from previous command
    let lastAckTimestamp = Date.now();
    console.log('initial lastAckTimestamp', lastAckTimestamp);

    return device.instant$.pipe(
      map(toDecodedAckFrame),
      filter(guardOnlyInstantAckValueDecodedData),
      filter(onlyMatchingTag),
      filter(({ timestamp }) => {
        console.log(
          'filter',
          timestamp,
          lastAckTimestamp,
          timestamp > lastAckTimestamp,
        );
        return timestamp > lastAckTimestamp;
      }),
      tap(({ timestamp }) => {
        console.log('tap', timestamp, lastAckTimestamp);

        lastAckTimestamp = timestamp;
      }),
      distinctUntilChanged(isEqual),
    );
  }, null);
```

I'm getting the following log

```
 LOG  initial lastAckTimestamp 1677164910821

 LOG  filter 1677164914666 1677164909553 true
 LOG  tap 1677164914666 1677164909553
 LOG  filter 1677164914666 1677164910821 true
 LOG  tap 1677164914666 1677164910821
 LOG  filter 1677164914666 1677164914666 false
 LOG  filter 1677164914666 1677164914666 false
```

I don't get how it's possible that `1677164910821` is on the second filter…

I'm having duplicated ack because of this.

Comment: Either it's caused by `device.instant$` or the maps

Comment: btw you should be using `scan` instead of using an outside variable

Comment: It's was becauce i'm updating legacy code and someone let another hook of same type mounted. 

BTW @MatthieuRiegler I've used distinctUntilKeyChanged('timestamp') thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that some legacy code from someone else was also running the same hook somewhere else in the rendered tree.

I've been able to detect it this way, as the list was more than 1.

```
const list = [];

export const useDeviceAck = (
  tags?: Tag[],
): InstantAckValueDecodedData | null => {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    list.push("Sub");
    console.log(list.length);

    return () => {
      list.pop()
   }
}
```

BTW also updated to this, which is more representative of my need

```
const ack = useObservable<InstantAckValueDecodedData | null>(
    () =>
      device.instant$.pipe(
        map(toDecodedAckFrame),
        filter(guardOnlyInstantAckValueDecodedData),
        filter(onlyMatchingTag),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged('timestamp'),
      ),
    null,
  );
```